# Alternative to c++ STD::map (need fast lower_bound method) in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I need alternative to std::map from cpp. I know about dictionary but it uses hash map, which doesn't support that always sorted feature. Ideally i need something in standard library.

More formaly I need data structure that is able to be always sorted and add elements in logarithmic time. Something like map accomplishes with red-black trees.

Edit: I need full sorted not just heap.
Edit 2: OrderedDict remembers order of insertion, but I need sorting ... If I insert median it should be inserted in the middle not the end.

Comment: Do you want a full sorted map, or just a heap?

Comment: Does `OrderedDict` work for this case? https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Hope I answered both questions in edits.

Comment: The [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html) is almost what you need, but I don't think it can insert in logarithmic time.

Comment: bisect module can do binary search but yeah the important part is logarithmic inserting.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, this module should provide what you need:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers

Especially:

http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html

Performance:

http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance-scale.html

> Alternative tree-based implementations have a runtime complexity
>   proportional to log_2{n} for adding elements. The logarithm grows much
>   more slowly than the cube root for large values of “n”. However, in
>   practice we never reach those large values and the constant factors
>   involved have a significant impact. Consider a billion elements:
>
> \log_2{1,000,000,000} \approx 33
>
> (1,000,000,000)^\frac{1}{3} \approx 1,000
>
> The constant factor between those is 1,000 / 33 \approx 33. So if the
>   operations for tree-based implementations are more than 33 times
>   slower, then SortedContainers may be faster.